# Unintended change of variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I do change List of Groups in method EditSelectList, it also affect ViewBag.Groups. Why is it happening? I assigned ViewBag earlier. It should not affect ViewBag.Groups and var tournamentsGroups

I have this code in controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Details2(int id)
{
    var tournamentsContext = new TournamentsContext();
    var tournament = tournamentsContext.Tournament.Single(t => t.Id == id);

    var groupsContext = new GroupsContext();
    var tournamentsGroups = groupsContext.Groups.Where(g => g.IdTournament == tournament.Id && g.SexMale == true).ToList();
    ViewBag.Groups = tournamentsGroups;

    ViewBag.groupId = new SelectList(EditSelectList(tournamentsGroups), "Id", "Belt");

    ViewBag.tournamentId = id;

    ViewBag.InTournament = CurrentUserInTournament(tournament.Id, currentUser);

    return View(tournament);
}

private List<Groups> EditSelectList(List<Groups> groups)
{
    foreach (var item in groups)
    {
        item.Belt = item.Belt + " - " + item.WeightKg; // for dropdownlist
    }

    return groups;
}
```

and View

```
@model TournamentApp.Models.Tournament

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Groups)
{
    if ("white".Equals(@item.Belt) || true)
    {
        <h4>@item.Belt</h4>
    }
}

// ... some another code for dropdownlist
```

so result is:

```
white - 65
white - 75
white - 85
blue - 75
```

but it should be just:

```
white
white
white
blue
```

Comment: `ToList()` returns a `List`. That you then *reference* from several locations (`ViewBag.Groups`, `tournamentsGroups`, and when you pass it to `EditSelectList`). But there's still only one `List` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the list in `ViewBag.Groups` still contains the same objects as the original list `tournamentsGroups`. The reference to the list is copied, its contents isn't changed at all. There is still just **one list**.

You need to copy the entire list and its items to prevent your subsequent actions to change the list you assign.

If you only use one property (`Belt`), you might want to create a new list of the `string`s, which is much easier than cloning every object. If you require to clone every since object, take a look at [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78536/993547).